# Outsheet to create a comma separated .txt

Tags: stata

My variables in Stata are of the form:

```
  First Name: Allen
  Last Name: Von Schmidt
  Birth Year: 1965
  County: Cape May
  State: New Jersey

  First Name: Lee Roy
  Last Name: McBride
  Birth Year: 1967
  County: Cook
  State: Illinois
```

I would like to outsheet them to create comma separated rows in a .txt as:

```
 Allen,Von Schmidt,1965,Cape May, New Jersey
 Lee Roy,McBride,1967,Cook, Illinois
```

How can I use outsheet (or another command) to do this?  Do I need to make the numerics into strings first?  Do I need to add a commas to each variable first?  Thanks!

Would something like the following work?

```
outsheet first last birth_year county state using FileName.txt, comma nolabel noquote
```

If I wanted to do the same thing but have the variables be " " separated would I remove the noquote in that previous stata code?

For example, suppose I might, instead, want an output of:

```
 "Allen","Von Schmidt","1965","Cape May","New Jersey"
```

Comment: Why not try it and see? It should work almost as in your example, except that if values of `State` don't start with spaces, `outsheet` will not insert them. Also, the variables or fields will be comma separated, _not_ the observations or rows.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a job that you would want to do with the `file` command, to keep full control over what is written to your file (especially if you have some possibly problematic ASCII characters like accents, which are common in names). See `h file` for the details.

I am not sure that I understand exactly what you have in your dataset, and in what format, so I will refrain from writing up a working example that would not fit your setup. The `file` command, however, is pretty straightforward (you can think of `outsheet` as a wrapper for it).

Comment: Fr.'s advice seems over-cautious here. I see no reason why `outsheet` should not work adequately; the only mystery is why the question was asked at all as it is easy enough to try it out to see.

Comment: I should have asked this awhile ago, but I just edited my post.  If I wanted to do the same thing but have the variables be " " separated as in the example I posted, would I remove the noquote in that previous stata code?

Comment: If you want space separation, use `delimiter(" ")`. Don't use `noquote` as then spaces in strings will mess up your file. This is easy enough to find out. (Historically, `outfile` was intended for this purpose, but `outsheet` seems to do fine.)

Comment: so do you mean: outsheet first last birth_year county state using FileName.txt, comma nolabel delimiter(" ") ?  As I wrote above, my goal, for example, is output of  "Allen","Von Schmidt","1965","Cape May","New Jersey" where each part inside the "" is a separate variable

Comment: it is saying that both comma and delimit are not possible.  should i do delim(" ",) ?

Comment: If you want comma separation, you ask for it using the `comma` option. `delimiter(" ")` is for space separation, which you seemed to be asking for. The double quote characters " " are not regarded by Stata as separators. They are punctuation binding strings.

Comment: so are you saying it is not possible to do the output that i'm asking for?  of "varible here", ?  meaning put the variable within a "" and then put a comma after the 2nd quote?  i just tried ,nolabel delim (" ") and it did not put the non-strings in quotes and it added a space that i did not want whereas i wanted the coma in place of this space

Comment: do i want nolabel delim(",") ?

Comment: Please ask a new question showing what you want. It's too crowded here.