# Deleting a File or Replacing a File when Outsheeting in Stata

Tags: shell, text-files, stata

I open up a .txt file.  Make some modifications to it.  Then I'd like to outsheet it with the same name.  To do this, I presume either I'd have to delete the file right before I outsheet it or replace the file in the outsheeting process.  As a backup, I can manually delete the .txt execute the relevant code.

I'd like to do this via Stata, however.  Is it possible to either:

```
1. Delete a .txt file within a Stata .doe--say with a shell command ?
2. Overwrite a .txt file in the outsheeting process ?
```

I am outsheeting as in:

```
 outsheet  v1 v2 using "file.txt", nolabel delim(",")
```

I run Stata in Windows on an XP machine.

Comment: You can solve many of the issues that you seem to be having by reading the documentation for outsheet, as you were already recommended to do in at least [one other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923255/outsheet-to-create-a-comma-separated-txt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the replace option anywhere after the comma.

You can can also `shell` out to the OS. Type "h shell" to see how.

Or just use `rm/erase` directly.

Comment: Dimitriy is quite correct. But the on-line help for `outsheet` is quite explicit:  `replace` as the option to overwrite existing filename is right at the start.